# Как свернуть окно Tk в трей Windows?

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, tkinter, system-tray

Есть прога, которую надо оставить работающей в фоновом режиме и свернуть в трей Windows. Нарыл вот такую ссылку: [тык](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/885630/%D0%98%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B2-%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B5-windows-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-tkinter)
Нифига не разобрался в этом вопросе, помогите понять как это делается на просто примере с tkinter, либо подскажите более лёгкий способ.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ну стало быть, нашел ты немного не то ;) На самом деле все проще и кроссплатформенней:

```
from pystray import MenuItem as item
import pystray
from PIL import Image
import tkinter as tk

window = tk.Tk()
window.title("Welcome")

def quit_window(icon, item):
    icon.stop()
    window.destroy()

def show_window(icon, item):
    icon.stop()
    window.after(0,window.deiconify)

def withdraw_window():  
    window.withdraw()
    image = Image.open("image.ico")
    menu = (item('Quit', quit_window), item('Show', show_window))
    icon = pystray.Icon("name", image, "title", menu)
    icon.run()

window.protocol('WM_DELETE_WINDOW', withdraw_window)
window.mainloop()
```

[source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54835399/running-a-tkinter-window-and-pystray-icon-together)

Comment: Привет) Да, делал небольшой перерыв, да и некоторые вопросы сам решал. Теперь восстанавливаюсь, надеюсь чаще буду задавать вопросы) Спасибо большое за ответ. В течении недели постараюсь проверить на работоспособность

Comment: @DGDays Ответ помог, или забыли, что ответы надо принимать? ;)