# Как снова открывать окно после закрытия tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

Есть [приложение](https://prnt.sc/YHaw0Cw0KK1q), работающее в трее, и при нажатии на кнопку в трее срабатывает функция открытия:

```
def on_click(icon, item):
   print("нажал")
   app.mainloop()
icon = pystray.Icon("Vodka vpn", image, menu = pystray.Menu(pystray.MenuItem("Вызвать меню", on_click, default=True)))
```

Также при нажатии на крестик для закрытия приложения я закрываю его методом destroy():

```
def on_close():
    print('закрыто')
    app.destroy()
app.protocol('WM_DELETE_WINDOW', on_close)
```

И после закрытия (после срабатывание функции on_close()) окно не открывается снова при нажатии на иконку в трее. При этом функция on_click() снова срабатывает (я это проверил) и ошибок никаких нет.

Comment: Не закрывайте, а скрывайте окно при попытке закрытия. Рабочий пример (дубликат?): [Как свернуть окно Tk в трей Windows?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1162558/1365)